# Why am I always getting random results regardless of seed value?

Tags: go

I have a fairly complex Go application. It generates many random results in a long chain. It is seeded only once - when an HTTP request comes in.

No matter what the seed is - whether it's unix time, or whether it's my own alphanumeric seed function - it *always* generates completely random results.

I've attempted cutting out my alphanumeric seed function, but that doesn't alter the behavior. I have also tried setting the seed always to 1111. This has no effect.

Here is a sample (verbose and lifted directly from the source, since that's what was requested):

```golang
func main() {
    sentryDSN := os.Getenv("SENTRY_DSN")

    sentry.Init(sentry.ClientOptions{
        Dsn: sentryDSN,
    })

    sentryHandler := sentryhttp.New(sentryhttp.Options{
        Repanic: true,
    })

    r := chi.NewRouter()

    r.Use(middleware.RequestID)
    r.Use(middleware.RealIP)
    r.Use(middleware.Logger)
    r.Use(middleware.Recoverer)
    r.Use(middleware.URLFormat)
    r.Use(middleware.SetHeader("Content-Type", "application/json"))

    r.Use(middleware.Timeout(60 * time.Second))

    r.Get("/buildingstyle", sentryHandler.HandleFunc(getBuildingStyleRandom))
    r.Get("/buildingstyle/{id}", sentryHandler.HandleFunc(getBuildingStyle))

    r.Get("/character", sentryHandler.HandleFunc(getCharacterRandom))
    r.Get("/character/{id}", sentryHandler.HandleFunc(getCharacter))

    r.Get("/climate", sentryHandler.HandleFunc(getClimateRandom))
    r.Get("/climate/{id}", sentryHandler.HandleFunc(getClimate))

    port := 7531
    fmt.Printf("World Generator API is running on http://localhost:%d.\n", port)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(fmt.Sprintf(":%d", port), r))
}

func SeedFromString(source string) error {
    h := md5.New()
    _, err := io.WriteString(h, source)
    if err != nil {
        err = fmt.Errorf("Failed to seed random number generator: %w", err)
        return err
    }
    seed := binary.BigEndian.Uint64(h.Sum(nil))
    rand.Seed(int64(seed))
    return nil
}

func getClimate(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    id := chi.URLParam(r, "id")

    var o climate.SimplifiedClimate

    err := random.SeedFromString(id)
    if err != nil {
        handleError(w, r, err)
        return
    }

    randomClimate, err := climate.Random()
    if err != nil {
        handleError(w, r, err)
        return
    }
    o = randomClimate.Simplify()

    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(o)
}

// Generate generates a climate with a given name
func Generate(name string) (Climate, error) {
    rawClimate, err := ByName(name)
    if err != nil {
        err = fmt.Errorf("Could not generate climate by name: %w", err)
        return Climate{}, err
    }
    climate, err := rawClimate.populate()
    if err != nil {
        err = fmt.Errorf("Could not generate climate by name: %w", err)
        return Climate{}, err
    }

    return climate, nil
}

func (climate Climate) populate() (Climate, error) {
    gems := mineral.Gems()
    insects := climate.getFilteredInsects()
    metals := mineral.Metals()

    stones := mineral.Stones()
    trees := climate.getFilteredTrees()

    climate.Seasons = climate.getSeasons()

    lakeChance := rand.Intn(100)
    riverChance := rand.Intn(100)
    oceanChance := rand.Intn(100)
    wetlandsChance := rand.Intn(100)

    if lakeChance > 30 {
        climate.HasLakes = true
    }
    if riverChance > 20 {
        climate.HasRivers = true
    }
    if oceanChance > 80 {
        climate.HasOcean = true
    }
    if wetlandsChance > 80 {
        climate.HasWetlands = true
    }

    soils := climate.getFilteredSoils()

    if climate.HasLakes || climate.HasRivers || climate.HasOcean {
        climate.Fish = climate.getFish()
    } else {
        climate.Fish = []fish.Fish{}
    }

    climate.Insects = insect.RandomSubset(7, insects)
    filteredMetals, err := mineral.RandomWeightedSet(climate.MaxMetals, metals)
    if err != nil {
        err = fmt.Errorf("Could not populate climate: %w", err)
        return Climate{}, err
    }
    climate.Metals = filteredMetals
    climate.Gems = mineral.Random(climate.MaxGems, gems)
    climate.OtherMinerals = mineral.OtherMinerals()

    climate.Animals, err = climate.getAnimals()
    if err != nil {
        err = fmt.Errorf("Could not populate climate: %w", err)
        return Climate{}, err
    }

    climate.Plants, err = climate.getPlants()
    if err != nil {
        err = fmt.Errorf("Could not populate climate: %w", err)
        return Climate{}, err
    }

    climate.Soils = soil.Random(climate.MaxSoils, soils)
    climate.Stones = mineral.Random(climate.MaxStones, stones)
    climate.Trees = tree.RandomSubset(climate.MaxTrees, trees)

    resources := climate.getResources()
    climate.Resources = resources

    description, err := climate.getDescription()
    if err != nil {
        err = fmt.Errorf("Could not populate climate: %w", err)
        return Climate{}, err
    }
    climate.Description = description

    climate.Habitability = climate.calculateHabitability()

    return climate, nil
}
```

Many of the functions like `doStuff()` return n random elements from a slice with some filtering applied.

All of this I expect to be consistent and identical when the same seed is used for multiple runs. However, this is not the case. Instead, the results are random every single time, regardless of seed value.

Is there some fundamental piece of `rand.Intn()`'s or `rand.Seed()`'s operation that I'm unaware of?

Comment: Please show actual code, not pseudo code. A [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is important. The details are what matter most in a question like this.

Comment: Not related to your question, but what is the perceived value of the `SeedFromString` function? Whether you use x, or a hash of x, the randomness factor is unchanged. So why waste all that code and CPU power to essentially do nothing?

Comment: Could you show us an example of how you're getting random numbers? And I don't see where you're calling `SeedFromString`.

Comment: But here's a guess, since there's no actual code to judge:  Are things happening in a non-deterministic order? Are you using goroutines (either directly, or behind the scenes with `net/http`, or somesuch)?  If so, then the random numbers can still be deterministic, but you may fetch them in a non-deterministic order, which may throw off expectations.

Comment: I'm extremely confused about what the desired result is. You seed random and you get random. Is the problem that you're seeding random with the same seed but getting different outputs?

Comment: I added actual code, rather than pseudocode. @CoreyOgburn, yes, I am seeding with the same seed, but getting different outputs.

Comment: That's not very "minimal" :/ Sentry doesn't seem related at all to the question.

Comment: It's also not complete. There's nothing in your pasted code that calls `populate()`, except `Generate()`, which in turn is not called.

Comment: Also: How are you testing this? Manually? A unit test? In production?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're seeding the default source, which is used by many parts of the system. In a large, complicated project, it is very likely that there is some other part that is consuming an indeterminate number of random values dependent on the environment. It's even possible that somewhere else in your code you have a call to `rand.Seed()`.

If you want your random values to be independent, create your own `rand.Rand` and use that for the pieces you want to be determined by your seed.

If you can reproduce this in a self-contained piece of code, then we can explore the specific case, but I expect when you create a self-contained piece of code the problem will go away because you will have removed the other value consumer(s).